# Flyway migration throwing Validation error for Sybase GOTO label by splitting the keyword in separate 'GO' and 'to'

Tags: flyway, sap-ase, goto

I'm trying to run flyway (6.3.3) migration in SYbase ASE on the sql below but getting a validation error.

```
declare @count smallint
select @count = 1
restart:
  print 'yes'
select @count = @count + 1
while @count <= 4
  goto restart
```

Flyway response is

```
Migration R__wes.sql failed
---------------------------
SQL State  : 37000
Error Code : 102
Message    : Incorrect syntax near '4'.
Line       : 1
Statement  : declare @count smallint
select @count = 1
restart:
  print 'yes'
select @count = @count + 1
while @count <= 4
```

The issue is that FLyway is breaking the `goto` keyword to

```
GO
to
```

which results in the error.

i.e.

```
declare @count smallint
select @count = 1
restart:
  print 'yes'
select @count = @count + 1
while @count <= 4

GO
to restart
```

I found a similar issue on SQL Server that was resolved last year
https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2307

Thanks in advance!

Comment: assuming that's the entire error message generated by Flyway, the Flyway parser (?) appears to have completely missed the `goto restart`, so I'm wondering if it was looking for something else after the `while @count <= 4`? and the only thing I'm coming up with is the optional `begin/end` delimiters; might be interesting to see if Flyway can process the code if you wrap the `goto restart` in a pair of `begin/end` delimiters; if that works, then I'm wondering if Flyway has any configs/settings that allow for a `while` loop that doesn't require the `begin/end` delimiters?

Comment: hey Mark - I tried adding begin/end delimiters as you suggested but that did not fix the issue. I included the response in the main thread

Comment: What did you update? the file `R__wes.sql`? Is this on linux or Windows? At this point just more guesses ... replace the `goto restart` with `print 'goto here'` to rule out an issue with the `goto` command? if on linux, review the file for any embedded (windows) carriage returns that could be causing an issue with parsing of the file (these can cause parsing issues for `isql`, too?  have any other scripts with a `goto` been successfully processed by Flyway?

Comment: Mark - yes I updated the R__wes.sql to wrap the  ```goto start``` with ```begin/end ``` as you suggested. That did not work.  I did narrow down that it's the ``` goto ``` is the issue. The existing stored procedures are valid and it is being used in production. I'm currently evaluating flyway and it is the first time I'm trying a 'goto label' with flyway.

Comment: yeah, I have no doubt the code works (sans Flyway) :-)  ; I was looking to rule out an issue with the actual file (eg, non-printable character screwing up the parsing); I've got zero experience with Flyway so ... I'm outta ideas ...

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark. Greatly appreciated. It's probably a bug in Flyway. There's a same issue in SQL Server last year which got fixed. - https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2307

Comment: mark - flyway is breaking the keyword ```goto``` to  ```Go``` and ```to``` on the next line.  I updated my findings in the main post

Answer (score 0):

I created a pull request for a possible fix - https://github.com/flyway/flyway/pull/2775